# What are the default process when a rails application is launched?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm fairly new to rails, but I noticed that after running a newly-created rails app (with `rails new blog`) that there are quite a few process that are started, and the app server itself is running with `puma`.

```
> ps
> 24427 ttys000    0:01.58 puma 3.12.1 (tcp://localhost:3000) [blog]  
> 24429 ttys000    0:00.02 /Users/rob/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/rb-fsevent-0.10.3/bin/fsevent_watch --format=otnetstring --latency 0.1 
> 24430 ttys000    0:00.02 /Users/rob/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/rb-fsevent-0.10.3/bin/fsevent_watch --format=otnetstring --latency 0.1 
> 24431 ttys000    0:00.02 /Users/robertkotcher/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/rb-fsevent-0.10.3/bin/fsevent_watch --format=otnetstring --latency 0.1 
> 24432 ttys000    0:00.02 /Users/rob/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/rb-fsevent-0.10.3/bin/fsevent_watch --format=otnetstring --latency 0.1 
> 24433 ttys000    0:00.02 /Users/rob/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/rb-fsevent-0.10.3/bin/fsevent_watch --format=otnetstring --latency 0.1 
> 24434 ttys000    0:00.02 /Users/rob/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/rb-fsevent-0.10.3/bin/fsevent_watch --format=otnetstring --latency 0.1 
> 24435 ttys000    0:00.02 /Users/rob/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/rb-fsevent-0.10.3/bin/fsevent_watch --format=otnetstring --latency 0.1 
> 24436 ttys000    0:00.02 /Users/rob/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/rb-fsevent-0.10.3/bin/fsevent_watch --format=otnetstring --latency 0.1 
> 24437 ttys000    0:00.02 /Users/rob/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/rb-fsevent-0.10.3/bin/fsevent_watch --format=otnetstring --latency 0.1 
> 24438 ttys000    0:00.02 /Users/rob/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/rb-fsevent-0.10.3/bin/fsevent_watch --format=otnetstring --latency 0.1
```

I thought Puma was a web server that is optionally added, but it seems here that it's running by default. Is that correct?

Secondly, what is this `rb-fsevent` gem and where is it being used?

Comment: `Puma` is not the web server, its an application server like `Webrick`, `Unicorn`, you still 
 use a web server like `apache`, `nginx`. The application server sits between the web server and your application

Comment: Thanks @Subash, I did not realize that but makes sense now that you mention it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you're correct

Puma is now the default rails server, it's good you can absolutely use it for development as well.

rb-fsevent is a process launched by rails to reload the relevant file when it has been edited so any changes are immediately reflected without having to restart the rails server (here puma)